# Errors when creating a macro to create a pivot table with a dynamic named range

Tags: excel, vba, macros, pivot-table

I am trying to a macro to create a pivot table from a sheet that changes in length.  Used a dynamic named range to capture but am getting a:

> Run Time Error 5 Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

"DATA" is my dynamic scoped named range. have corrected to the below and now get a "Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed because I am not referencing a specific sheet?

`With ActiveWorkbook.Names("DATA")
        .Name = "DATA"
        .RefersToR1C1 = _
        "=OFFSET('Closed Cases'!R1C2,0,0,COUNTA('Closed Cases'!C6),25)"
        .Comment = ""
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        Range("DATA"), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "'External Analytics!'R1C15", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("External Analytics").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select`

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a `Range` object to `SourceData` argument

If "Data" is a Workbook scoped named Range you want to type:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
Range("Data"), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
"'External Analytics!'R1C15", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:= _
xlPivotTableVersion14
```